# Issue converting Java bean with inheritance to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

On the current Java class we have 2 Java beans Clazz1 and Clazz2 where both extend super class SuperClazz. We also have a list where we iterate the super class entries which can be Clazz1 or Clazz2:

```
List<SuperClazz> entries;
```

We now need to convert the code to Kotlin but since *data class* does not support inheritance we are unsure on the best way to tackle the issue, do we just create a standard Kotlin class with variables, extends the super class, and manually craft the getter-setters? Or, is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typically 2 (not mutual) ways you can kill the need for class inheritance:

#### 1. Use composition

Extract the pieces that are common between `Clazz1` and `Clazz2` into separate class. i.e

```
data class SharedStuff(val a:Int, val b:String)
data class Class1(val stuff:SharedStuff, val other:String)
data class Class2(val stuff:SharedStuff, val specific:Int)
```

Which you can then use in a list for instance

```
class Container {
    private var items = listOf<()->SharedStuff>()
    fun add(a:Class1) { items += { a.stuff } }
    fun add(b:Class2) { items += { b.stuff } }
}
```

#### 2. Use interfaces

From the example above it's easy to follow that you can extract an interface to represent the common inside `Class1` and `Class2` like so:

```
interface HasStuff { val stuff:SharedStuff }

data class SharedStuff(val a:Int, val b:String)
data class Class1(override val stuff:SharedStuff, val other:String) : HasStuff
data class Class2(override val stuff:SharedStuff, val specific:Int) : HasStuff

class Container {
    private var items = listOf<HasStuff>()
    fun add(a:HasStuff) { items += a }
}
```

Note that we do not necessarily need the `SharedStuff` as class. You can also have more members on the shared interface and still achieve brevity [through Kotlin's delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#delegation). *(However it's usually better [to have "small" interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle))*

Comment: We decided to do it:
   interface HasStuff { val sharedDt:Int }
   data class Class1(override val sharedDt:Int, val other:String) : HasStuff
   data class Class2(override val sharedDt:Int, val specific:Int) : HasStuff
   
   class Container {
       private var items = listOf<HasStuff>()
       fun add(a:HasStuff) { items += a }
   }

Answer (score 1):

We decided to do it:

```
   interface HasStuff { val sharedDt:Int }
   data class Class1(override val sharedDt:Int, val other:String) : HasStuff
   data class Class2(override val sharedDt:Int, val specific:Int) : HasStuff

   class Container {
       private var items = listOf<HasStuff>()
       fun add(a:HasStuff) { items += a }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> do we just create a standard Kotlin class with variables, extends the super class, and manually craft the getter-setters?

Pretty much, yeah, although not with *variables* but with *properties*. If your `SuperClazz` doesn't have any fields, then you might be able to convert it to an interface, and data classes can implement interfaces - you'd still have to implement the methods though, but that would enable you to utilize the same architecture (iterate over super-typed parameter collection). There isn't any way to use data class auto-properties in the way you describe.